# How to extract all <p> with its corresponding <h2>?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the `<p>` that come after `<h2>`.

I know how to do this in case I have only one `<p>` after `<h2>`, but not in case I have multiple `<p>`.

Here's an example of the webpage:

```
<h2>Heading Text1</h2>

<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>

<h2>Heading Text2</h2>

<p>Paragraph3</p>
<p>Paragraph4</p>
<p>Paragraph5</p>
....
```

I need to get all paragraphs in relation to their headings, e.g. Paragraphs 1 and 2 that are related to Heading Text1.

I'm trying that using `BeautifulSoup` with `Python`, been trying for days, also googling.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get your goal while working with a `dict` and `.find_previous()` - Iterate all `<p>`, find its previous `<h2>` and set it as key in your `dict`, than simply append the texts to its `list`:

```
d = {}
for p in soup.select('p'):
    if p.find_previous('h2'):
        if d.get(p.find_previous('h2').text) == None:
            d[p.find_previous('h2').text]=[]
    else:
        continue
    d[p.find_previous('h2').text].append(p.text)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p>Any Other Paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading Text1</h2>

<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>

<h2>Heading Text2</h2>

<p>Paragraph3</p>
<p>Paragraph4</p>
<p>Paragraph5</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

d = {}
for p in soup.select('p'):
    if p.find_previous('h2'):
        if d.get(p.find_previous('h2').text) == None:
            d[p.find_previous('h2').text]=[]
    else:
        continue
    d[p.find_previous('h2').text].append(p.text)
d
```

##### Output

```
{'Heading Text1': ['Paragraph1', 'Paragraph2'],
 'Heading Text2': ['Paragraph3', 'Paragraph4', 'Paragraph5']}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! any chance we can get it to work if the there was one or more p tags above the first h tag?

Comment: Simply check if there is a `find.previous('h2)` - Edited the example.

Comment: Hey, I've got an issue with that though, each paragraph may have a word like "this guy's phone", and when it's returned it comes back as "this guy\'s phone".
How can I fix that before assigning each paragraph to the list?
I've alreadly tried strip() and replace(), in any spot in the loop that I found...

Comment: To keep OP clean and focused, this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and a [mcve] to be able to reproduce your issue - We will notice it and you have chance for practice. Would be great.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost identical to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743041/how-to-get-text-from-and-html-with-a-bit-weird-structure) posed yesterday. You can solve this in few different ways. Here is how I would do it:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h2>Heading Text1</h2>

<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>

<h2>Heading Text2</h2>

<p>Paragraph3</p>
<p>Paragraph4</p>
<p>Paragraph5</p>

<h2>Heading Text3</h2>

<p>Paragraph6</p>
<p>Paragraph7</p>
<p>Paragraph8</p>
<p>Paragraph9</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
data_dict = {}
for item in soup.select("h2"):
    header = item.get_text(strip=True)
    content = []
    for i in item.next_siblings:
        if i.name=="h2": break
        content.extend([x for x in i.stripped_strings])
    data_dict[header] = content

print(data_dict)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But, there's a slight issue, when having <a href> I'm getting a new line and then the rest of the content (in p tags), something like that, cannot really explain.
How can we solve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, I will get all the `h2`, `p` tags and iterate through them saving the last `h2` tag content and tying it to the paragraphs next to it.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<h2>Heading Text1</h2>

<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>

<h2>Heading Text2</h2>

<p>Paragraph3</p>
<p>Paragraph4</p>
<p>Paragraph5</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

dict_to_save = {}

# find all the 'h2' and 'p' tags
for tag in soup(['h2','p']):
    # if 'h2' tag save it into a variable named header
    if tag.name == 'h2':
        header = tag.text.strip()

    # if not 'h2' tag add this paragraph to the last header
    else:
        dict_to_save[header] = dict_to_save.get(header, []) + [tag.text.strip()]

print(dict_to_save)
```

```
{'Heading Text1': ['Paragraph1', 'Paragraph2'],
 'Heading Text2': ['Paragraph3', 'Paragraph4', 'Paragraph5']}
```

Comment: Actually that's not gonna work (it hasn't), your variable "header" is referenced when it's not set in the else statement.