# How to collect siblings between two specific siblings?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html book with many `<h2>` headers and I want to collect the content after each of them using `beautifulsoup`. This is my current code which crashes, because it is just adding over and over again every sibling through the entire document and then repeating the element loop:

```
chapter_data = []

for e in soup.select('h2'): # select the tags

    chapter = ''

    for sib in e.next_siblings:

        if sib.name == 'h2':
            break
        
        chapter += str(sib)
        
        # add data to list
        chapter_data.append({
            'chapter': e.get_text(strip=True).split()[-1],
            'text': chapter
        })


chapters = pd.DataFrame(chapter_data)
```

The goal is getting each chapter into its own cell. I figured that this would collect all the siblings and content after each `<h2></h2>` tag separately to store it in a list. There are a lot of headings and I could manually do this, but I would like to know the proper code that could do this for me.

I tried an `extract()` method but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract all <p> with its corresponding <h2>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756733/how-to-extract-all-p-with-its-corresponding-h2)

Comment: that doesn't quite answer it. though it's close. I need all the tags included, not just the text, and it appends data into a dictionary that can't be converted easily to a dataframe as my code intends

Comment: First and foremost, it should be a suggestion that can be adapted and a `dict` is predestined to generate a `dataframe` from it - but it is nice to see that it comes close. Probably an improvement of the question with details, an HTML example structure / URL and the expected result would allow a more targeted answer. Would be great and I am curious about the use case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How you did it is pretty much what I would do, but you should unindent the *`chapter_data.append...`* statement by a level since there is no need to append to `chapter_data` for every `sib`. The example below parses [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_gas).

```py
# [ linkToSoup defined at https://pastebin.com/rBTr06vy ]
# soup = linkToSoup('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_gas') 

headerTags = soup.select('h2')
chapter_data, totalCh = [], len(headerTags)
for ci, (h, nxt_h) in enumerate(zip(headerTags, headerTags[1:]+[None]), 1):
    print('', end=f'\rAdding chapter {ci} of {totalCh}') ## track progress

    texts, htmls = '', ''
    for sib in h.next_siblings:
        if sib == nxt_h: break
        if callable(getattr(sib, 'get_text', None)): 
            texts += '\n' + sib.get_text(' ', strip=True)
        htmls += '\n' + str(sib).strip()
    
    # texts = BeautifulSoup(htmls).get_text(' ', strip=True)
    chapter_data.append({
        'chapter': h.get_text(' ', strip=True),
        'text': texts.strip(), 'html': htmls.strip()
    })
print('\n')

chapters = pd.DataFrame(chapter_data)
```

Output:

> [image: opdf]

---

Btw, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SAoe.png) is what it would look like if my *`chapter_data.append...`* statement was indented like yours - there would be many redundant `append`s for each chapter.

---

EDIT: just realized that you can probably get your `chapter_data` in one statement with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
chapter_data = [{
    'chapter': h.get_text(' ', strip=True),
    'html': '\n'.join(
        str(sib) for sib in h.next_siblings if
        sib!=nxt_h and nxt_h not in sib.previous_siblings
    ).strip()
} for h, nxt_h in zip(headerTags, headerTags[1:]+[None])]
```

[View Screenshot with Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYh9D.png)